# local WPMU on Debian Lenny vm - 404 error on blog post

Tags: debian, apache-2.2, virtual-machines, wordpress

I successfully installed wordpress multiuser on my Lenny virtual machine. I set up mod_rewrite and domain in /etc/hosts for it. I can login to dashboard, main page loads too. Only problem I have are blog posts... When i click on default hello world post to check if everything is ok i get 404 error (i see wordpress 404 page, not apache 404). How could i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can see the "Hello world" post from the blog's front page, but you get a 404 error from WordPress when you click the link, then I wonder if it's a problem with WordPress's links structure.

Have you changed the permalinks defaults? (If so, the blog itself will offer you a handy-dandy set of rules to put into a .htaccess file.)

Comment: I don't see hello world from main page because it's MU and its default template doesn't show posts, just links to posts and link to admin panel ;). Yes, I'm wondering if it's permalinks error too (since i got wp 404, not apache 404). I didn't changed defaults yet. I'm on different machine now, but later I'll check .htaccess and I'll post it here if i won't figure out what's wrong with it.

Comment: I updated permalinks structure in wp admin and it seems to work... now i feel dumb for asking ;). Hmmmmmmm.